# How to connect a printer to printService?

Tags: android, printing

I'd want to be able to print on one specific printer, chosen programmatically with its DNS name, among several printers on the same network than my android device.

I try to implement the `printService` and the `PrinterDiscoverySession` to be able to add a printer.

Here is where I'm lost.
I'm able to add aprinter like this :

```
@Override
public void onStartPrinterDiscovery(@NonNull List<PrinterId> priorityList) {

    final List<PrinterInfo> printers = new ArrayList<>();
    final PrinterId printerId = generatePrinterId("Brother HL-L6300DW series");
    final PrinterInfo.Builder builder = new PrinterInfo.Builder(printerId, "Brother HL-L6300DW series", PrinterInfo.STATUS_IDLE);
    PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder capBuilder = new PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(printerId);
    capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4, true);
    capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A3, false);
    capBuilder.addResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("resolutionId", "default resolution", 600, 600), true);
    capBuilder.setColorModes(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR | PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME, PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR);
    builder.setCapabilities(capBuilder.build());
    printers.add(builder.build());
    addPrinters(printers);
}
```

But how can you attach this new virtual printer to a real one, with its name or its IP address ?

Edit:
This is what the code above give to me, in parameters/print screen:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your questions is not clear. It is the PrintService job to provide actual printers. Your PrintService need to be able to communicate with the actual printer and report its capabilities via addPrinters.

Comment: Besides, you cannot force the print framework to show only your printer. Depending on what other print services are installed on the Android device, other printers could show up, with the default selection controlled by the print framework

Comment: OK, I need to implement something to communicate with the printer before using the PrintService.
But even if I the application can do that, where can I make a link with the printer via the addPrinter method ? If I use the code above, I am able to make the added printer like the screenShot I've added. But if I choose this "fake" printer, how can I make the communication with the real printer that should after the printer choice on the android device ?

Comment: You'd need to fully implement the PrintService/PrinterDiscoverySession classs, which would respond to callbacks such as onStartPrinterStateTracking (reporting the printer attributes when the user selects it), onPrintJobQueued(PrintJob)  printing the job when the user taps on the print button .. etc